# Include Angular Directives into a custom made directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using an awesome, custom-made autocomplete directive called [Almighty-Autocomplete](https://github.com/JustGoscha/allmighty-autocomplete). However I'm missing some functionality.

The general directive looks like:

```
.directive('autocomplete', function () {
 var index = -1;

 return {
   restrict: 'E',
   scope: {
     searchParam: '=ngModel',
     suggestions: '=data',
     onType: '=onType',
     onSelect: '=onSelect'
   },
   controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {...}
   link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

     var attr = '';

     // Default atts
     scope.attrs = {
       "placeholder": "start typing...",
       "class": "",
       "id": "",
       "inputclass": "",
       "inputid": ""
     };
   } ....
```

The template looks like:

```
<div class="autocomplete {{ attrs.class }}" id="{{ attrs.id }}">
<input
    type="text"
    ng-model="searchParam"
    placeholder="{{ attrs.placeholder }}"
    class="{{ attrs.inputclass }}"
    id="{{ attrs.inputid }}"/>
</div>
```

I'm not yet savvy enough to add my own stuff into the directive. So I'd like to know **how can I add the Angular directives `ng-blur` and `ng-focus` into the autocomplete directive**, so that when I use it

```
<autocomplete ng-model="truck.license.number" 
              attr-placeholder="VD 102 203" data="placa_numeros"
              on-type="updateNumeros"
              on-select="select"
              ng-blur="offFocus()"
              ng-focus="onFocus()">
</autocomplete>
```

I can have `ng-blur` and `ng-focus` perform a function.

Answer (score 0):

Those **angular directive** were meant to be used with specific HTML elements not any elements. For example if you reivew the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus) for `ngFocus` it will tell you that it was meant to be in use in :

```
window, input, select, textarea, a
```

So in order to used those directives in your *custom directive* instead of using "`autocomplete`" as element you will need to use one of the elements above.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that the template for the autocomplete is an <input>.